# ¿Como puedo cambiar el idioma de las opciones que incluye SearchPanes de Datatables?

Tags: datatables

Estoy utilizando datatables y lo traduje utilizando el json en español, pero este cambio no se aplica al complemento SearchPanes, no he encontrado la documentación para cambiar el idioma de las opciones.

Este es el código que utilizo para modificar Datatables y Searchpanes

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tablax').DataTable({
            columnDefs:[
        {
            searchPanes:{
                initCollapsed: true,
                show: false,
                cascadePanes: true,
                layout: 'columns-4',
                dtOpts: {
                    dom: 'tp',
                    paging: 'true',
                    pagingType: 'numbers',
                    searching: true
                },
                targets: [0,1,2,3]
            }}],
            dom: 'Plrtip',
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
            },
            scrollY: 700,
            ordering: false,
            lengthMenu: [
                [20, 50, -1],
                [20, 50, "Todos"]
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image: Y estas son las opciones que me gustarían traducir]

Comment: has probado a quitarle las comillas a `language`?

Comment: Prueba con poner lo del `language` dentro de `dtOpts` (quitándole las comillas a _"language"_) y dinos si ha funcionado (teoricamente deberia segun leo en [su documentación](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchPanes.i18n))

Comment: Gracias a ambos por la ayuda!! Language debe estar sin comillas y dentro del dtOpts, al hacer ese cambio se traduce el filtro de arriba!!! Pero no lo botones... Si ven alguna parte de la documentación que ayude con eso lo agradeceré mucho.

Comment: Si vas aqui: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ y pulsas sobre el grupo SearchPanes aparece una lista de opciones. Busca las que empiezan por searchPanes.i18n y alli deberias encontrar lo que te falte

Comment: He agregado una respuesta a tu problema conforme a lo que hemos ido comentando. Si consideras que da solución a tu problema deberias aceptarla para que no quede pendiente eternamente y para que la comunidad lo sepa. En este enlace encontraras algunas instrucciones sobre como aceptarla, gracias:  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun la [documentación de SearchPanes](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchPanes.i18n), la opción de `language` debe ir dentro de `dtOpts`, así:

```
dtOpts: {
    language: {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
    },
    etc...
```

Para el resto de **opciones de internacionalización**, como por ejemplo algunos **botones**, son las opciones que empiezan por **searchPanes.i18n** en la lista de opciones que aparecen al pulsar sobre el botón de grupo ***SearchPanes*** en esta página: https://datatables.net/reference/option/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por toda su ayuda, lo he resuelto con esto!!

Comment: De nada. Me alegro :-)